# Compare the topology of pointwise convergence with the vector topology in the space of the continuous scalar functions $C(I)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence, topological-vector-spaces

So given the set
$$
C(I):=\{f\in\Bbb R^I:f\,\text{continuous}\}
$$
where $I=[a,b]$ is a closed interval of the real line it is not hard to show that for any $f,g\in C(I)$ and for any $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ the equations
$$
(f+g)(x):=f(x)+g(x)\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,(\lambda\cdot f)(x):=\lambda\cdot f(x)
$$
for any $x\in I$ make $C(I)$ a vector space. Now it is also a well know result that the equation
$$
L_2(f,g):=\int_If\cdot g
$$
for any $f,g\in C(I)$ defines an inner product over $C(I)$ so that this set is a topological vector space. However, it is well known that the equation
$$
d_\infty(f,g):=\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in I\}
$$
defines a metric in $C(I)$. Finally for any $x_1,\dots,x_n\in I$ putting
$$
[f;x_1,\dots,x_n;r]:=\{g\in C(I):|f(x_i)-g(x_i)|<r\,\,\,\forall i=1,\dots,n\}
$$
the collection
$$
\mathcal B_p:=\{[f;x_1,\dots,x_n;r]:f\in C(I)\wedge r\in\Bbb R^+\}
$$
defines a topology on $C(I)$.

So observing that
$$
d_{L_2}(f,g)=\|f-g\|_{L_2}=\Biggl|\int_I f-g\Biggl|\le\int_I|f-g|\le\int_I\sup|f-g|=\\
\sup|f-g|\cdot\int_I 1\le\frac r{b-a}(b -a)=r
$$
for any $g\in\mathcal B_\infty\Big(f,\frac r{b-a}\Big)$ we conclude that
$$
\mathcal B_{\infty}\Big(f,\frac r{b-a}\Big)\subseteq\mathcal B_{L_2}(f,r)
$$
so that the topology $\mathcal T_\infty$ generated by $d_\infty$ contains the topology $\mathcal T_{L_2}$ generated by $L_2$, that is
$$
\mathcal T_{L_2}\subseteq\mathcal T_\infty
$$
After all the functions $f,g$ are continuous in $I$ so that for any $r>0$  there exist $\delta_{f_i},\delta_{g_i}$ for any $i=1,\dots,n$ such that
$$
|f(x)-f(x_i)|<\frac r 3\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,|g(x)-g(x_i)|<\frac r 3
$$
for any $x\in I$ such that
$$
|x-x_i|<\min\big\{\delta_{f_i},\delta_{g_i}\big\}
$$
so that let be
$$
\delta_i:=\min\big\{\delta_{f_i},\delta_{g_i}\big\}
$$
for any $i=1,\dots,n$.

So given $x\in I$ such that $|x-x_i|<\delta_i$ for any $i=1,\dots,n$ we observe that
$$
|f(x_i)-g(x_i)|=\Big|\big(f(x_i)-f(x)\big)+\big(g(x)-g(x_i)\big)+(f(x)-g(x)\big)\Big|\le|f(x_i)-f(x)|+|g(x)-g(x_i)|+|f(x)-g(x)|\le\frac r 3+\frac r 3+\sup|f-g|\le\frac 2 3 r+\frac r 3=r
$$
for any $g\in\mathcal B_\infty\Big(f,\frac r 3\Big)$ and thus we conclude that
$$
\mathcal B_\infty\Big(f,\frac r 3\Big)\subseteq[f;x_1,\dots,x_n;r]
$$
and this allows to conclude that the topology $\mathcal T_p$ generated by the collection $\mathcal B_p$ is contained in the topology $\mathcal T_\infty$ generated by the metric $d_\infty$, that is
$$
\mathcal T_p\subseteq\mathcal T_\infty
$$

So **first of all** I ask if the arguments I gave to compare the topologies $\mathcal T_{L_2}$, $\mathcal T_p$ and $\mathcal T_\infty$ are correct and then I ask to compare the topology $\mathcal T_{L_2}$ and $\mathcal T_p$.

So could someone help me, please?

Comment: So you want to compare $L_2$, uniform, and pointwise convergence?

Comment: Yes, you understood.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. It seems I did any progress: what can you say about my edit of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed $\mathcal{T}_p, \mathcal{T}_{L_2} \subseteq \mathcal{T}_\infty$ is correct (and the proofs work too).

You do make the $\mathcal{T}_p \subseteq \mathcal{T}_\infty$ argument too hard: it's clear from the definitions that $$B_\infty(f,r) \subseteq [f;x_1, \ldots,x_n; r]$$ for any finite subset $\{x_1,\ldots x_n\}$ of $I$ and $r>0$. You don't even need continuity of $f$ for that.

$\mathcal{T}_p \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ for a topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $C(I)$ iff for each $x \in I$ we have that the map $f \to f(x)$ from $(C(I),\mathcal{T})$ to $\Bbb R$ is continuous. Is this the case here?

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that $\mathcal T_p\subseteq\mathcal T$ iff the map $x\rightarrow f(x)$ is continuous **with respect $\mathcal T$**, right? If you want mean this I reflected about but I am not able to see immediately if this map is continuous with respect $\mathcal T_{L_2}$ so I ask if you can say something about. Anyway thanks for  promptness with which you answered.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro yes in $\mathcal{T}$ obviously. This fact is the reason it’s called the pointwise topology.

Comment: Okay, so I will reflect about the continuity of the map $x\rightarrow f(x)$...

Comment: It seem not trivial to clarify this in the $L_2$-topology.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro look for sequential continuity. Also see edit.

Comment: Oh yeah! Indeed $C(I)$ is a metric space with respect $L_2$-topology  and any metric space is first contable so that a function $\phi$ is continuous iff the sequence $\phi(f_n)$ converges to $\phi(f)$ when $f_n$ converges to $f$, right? So I have to prove that the sequence $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro hint: consider $f_n = t^n$ at $x=1$.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understeand clearly  if $t$ is a costant or a variable. Anyway provided it was a variable then $f_n(x)$ was convergent and so the counterexample does not work so that I conclude that it is a constant, right? Moreover I was not able to determine the limit of $f_n$ in the $L_2$-topology but by your counterexample I argue that the pointwise topology is not contained in the $L_2$-topology, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro $f$, the limit of the power functions is the constant $0$ map. Do you see that in the $L_2$ topology?

Comment: Oh yes, I see: indeed $$\Biggl|\int_0^1x^n-0\Biggl|=\frac 1{n+1}<\epsilon$$ for any $n\ge \frac 1 \epsilon -1$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro now what is $f_n(1)$ for all $n$?  And $f(0)$? Conclusion?

Comment: So  $f_n\rightarrow f=0$ but $f_n(1)\rightarrow 1\neq f(0)$ and so we conclude that $\mathcal T_p$ is not  contained in $\mathcal T_{L_2}$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro indeed. That’s the final conclusion. We’ve found a sequence that converges for $L_2$ but not for $\mathcal{T}_p$.

Comment: Okay, very fine: obviously $\mathcal T_{L_2}$ cannot be contained in $\mathcal T_p$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro yes, the topologies are incomparable.

Comment: Oaky, question approved: thanks very much for your assistance!!! See you soon.