# If $φ:I→J$ is a homeomorphism then $f_n→f$ implies that $(f_n∘φ) →(f∘φ)$ with respect the uniform, pointwise and $L_2$ topology respectively?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, topological-vector-spaces, sequence-of-function

So given the set
$$
C(I):=\{f\in\Bbb R^I:f\,\text{continuous}\}
$$
where $I=[a,b]$ is a closed interval of the real line it is not hard to show that for any $f,g\in C(I)$ and for any $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ the equations
$$
(f+g)(x):=f(x)+g(x)\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,(\lambda\cdot f)(x):=\lambda\cdot f(x)
$$
for any $x\in I$ make $C(I)$ a vector space. Now it is also a well know result that the equation
$$
L_2(f,g):=\int_If\cdot g
$$
for any $f,g\in C(I)$ defines an inner product over $C(I)$ so that this set is a topological vector space. However, it is well known that the equation
$$
d_\infty(f,g):=\sup\{|f(x)-g(x)|:x\in I\}
$$
defines a metric in $C(I)$ whose topology $\mathcal T_\infty$ is said *topology of uniform convergence* or rather *uniform topology*. Finally for any $x_1,\dots,x_n\in I$ putting
$$
[f;x_1,\dots,x_n;r]:=\{g\in C(I):|f(x_i)-g(x_i)|<r\,\,\,\forall i=1,\dots,n\}
$$
the collection
$$
\mathcal B_p:=\{[f;x_1,\dots,x_n;r]:f\in C(I)\wedge r\in\Bbb R^+\}
$$
defines a topology on $C(I)$ said *topology of pointwise convergence* or rather *pointwise topology*.

---

So let be now $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ a sequence of functions defined in an interval $I$ and thus let be $\varphi$ a homoeomprhism from an interval $J$ to $I$. So, I would like understand if the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges pointwisely or uniformly in $I$ then also the sequence $(f_n\circ\varphi)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges respectively pointwisely or uniformly.

First of all I tried to prove that if $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly then also $(f_n\circ\varphi)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly and precisely I tried to do this observing that if $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic topological spaces then a net $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ on $X$ converges to $x$ if and only if for any homeomorphism $\phi$ from $X$ to $Y$ the net $\big(\phi(x_\lambda)\big)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ converges on $Y$ to $\phi(x)$. Indeed, knowing this result I defined a map $\Phi$ from $C(I)$ to $C(J)$ through the equation
$$
\Phi(f):=f\circ\varphi
$$
for any $f\in C(I)$ and thus I attempted to prove that it is a homeomorphism and I did this as to follow. So first of all, I defined the application $\Phi^{-1}$ form $C(J)$ to $C(I)$ through the equation
$$
\Phi^{-1}(g):=g\circ\varphi^{-1}
$$
for any $g\in C(J)$ and thus I observed that for any $f\in C(I)$ and for any $g\in C(J)$ the equalities
$$
\big(\Phi^{-1}\circ\Phi\big)(f)=\Phi^{-1}\big(\Phi(f)\big)=\Phi^{-1}(f\circ\varphi)=(f\circ\varphi)\circ\varphi^{-1}=f
\\\text{and}\\
\big(\Phi\circ\Phi^{-1}\big)(g)=\Phi\big(\Phi^{-1}(g)\big)=\Phi(g\circ\varphi^{-1})=(g\circ\varphi^{-1})\circ\varphi=g
$$
hold so that I concluded that $\Phi$ is bijective and in particular $\Phi^{-1}$ is exactly its inverse. Now, the application $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$ are surjective so that
$$
\sup|(f\circ\varphi)-(h\circ\varphi)|=\sup|f-h|\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,
\sup|(g\circ\varphi^{-1})-(k\circ\varphi^{-1})|=\sup|g-k|
$$
for any $f,h\in C(I)$ and for any $(g,k)\in C(J)$ and thus I conclude that $\Phi$ and $\Phi^{-1}$ are isometry and so they are, in particular, continuous and this proves that $\Phi$ is properly a homeomorphism with respect the unfirom topolgy.

Well, we observe now that if $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence on $C(I)$ then for any finite sequence $(x_i)_{i=1}^n$ of elements of $I$ the numerical sequence $\Big((f_n\circ\varphi)\big(\varphi^{-1}(x_i)\big)\Big)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ for $i=1,\dots ,n$ converges to $(f\circ\varphi)(\varphi^{-1}(x_i)\big)$ for any $f\in C(I)$ wheter the numerical sequence $\big(f_n(x_i)\big)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ for $i=1,\dots, n$ converges to $f(x_i)$: indeed if $\big(f_n(x_i)\big)$ converges to $f(x_i)$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ ther exist $n_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that
$$
\Big|(f_n\circ\varphi)\big(\varphi^{-1}(x_i)\big)-(f\circ\varphi)\big(\varphi^{-1}(x_i)\big)\Big|=|f_n(x_i)-f(x_i)|<\epsilon
$$
for any $n\ge n_\epsilon$ so that the statement follows trivially. So we conclude that if $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges pointwisely at $x$ then $(f_n\circ\varphi)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges pointwisely at $\varphi^{-1}(x)$: however, I was not able to understand if the last argumentations show that the application $\Phi$ is also a homeomorphism with respect the pointwise topology and I would not dislike to understand this.

So, I'd like finally understand if the $L_2$ convergence on $I=(a,b)$ implies the $L_2$ convergence on $J=(c,d)$. Unfortunately, I was not able to say anything about - I was not only able to prove the $L_2$ convergence on $I$ implies $L_2$ convergence on $J$ and vice versa but I was not able to find a counterexample showing the contrary. Anyway [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4331754/compare-the-topology-of-pointwise-convergence-with-the-vector-topology-in-the-sp) is showed that the inclusion
$$
\mathcal T_p,\mathcal T_{L_2}\subseteq\mathcal T_\infty
$$
holds so that the uniform convergence implies the $L_2$ convergence and thus this let to state that if $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence on $I$ converging uniformly then it converges with respect $L_2$ topology and in particular by the previous arguments also $(f_n\circ\varphi)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges with respect $L_2$. Moreover, let be $P_0(I)$ and $N_0(I)$ the subsets of $C(I)$ defined through the equation
$$
P_0(I):=\{f\in C(I):f(x)\ge0\,\forall x\in I\}\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,N_0(I):=\{f\in C(I):f(x)\le 0\,\forall x\in I\}
$$
and thus we observe that they are linear subspace and in particular
$$
fg\ge 0
$$
for any $f,g\in P_0\cup N_0$. Now we suppose that $\varphi$ is of class $C^1$ so that by the Weierstrass theorem $|D\varphi|$ is bounded and thus observing that
$$
\Big(d_{L_2}(f\circ\varphi,g\circ\varphi)\Big)^2=\big\|(f\circ\varphi)-(g\circ\varphi)\big\|_{L_2}^2=\biggl|\int_J(fg)\circ\varphi\biggl|=\\
\biggl|\int_{\varphi[J]}\big((fg)\circ\varphi\big)\circ\varphi^{-1}\cdot\big|\det D\varphi\big|\biggl|=
\biggl|\int_I(fg)\cdot|D\varphi|\biggl|=\\
\int_I(fg)\cdot |D\varphi|\le\int_I(fg)\le\max|D\varphi|=\max|D\varphi|\cdot\int_Ifg=\\
\max|D\varphi|\cdot\big\|f-g\big\|_{L_2}^2=\max|D\varphi|\cdot\Big(d_{L_2}(f,g)\Big)^2
$$
for any $f,g\in P_0(I)\cup N_0(I)$ we concluded that if $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence on $P_0\cup N_0$ converging to $f\in P_0(I)\cup N_0(I)$ then $(f_n\circ\varphi)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to $f\circ\varphi\in P_0(J)\cup N_0(J)$ and moreover this surely happens if $P_0(I)$ and $N_0(I)$ was closed but unfortunately I was not able to clarify this. Anyway if $\varphi$ is of class $C^1$ then, as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338799/c1-function-on-compact-set-is-lipschitz) showed, it is a lipschit function but unfortunately it seems that this does not help to understand if the $L_2$ topology on $I$ is *compatible* with the $L_2$ topology on $J$ through $\varphi$. Finally, we suppose that
$$
\varphi(x):=\frac{b-a}{d-c}\cdot(x-c)+a
$$
for any $x\in J$ and thus we observe that if $d-c\le b-a$ then
$$
\Big(d_{L_2}(f\circ\varphi,g\circ\varphi)\Big)^2=\big\|(f\circ\varphi)-(g\circ\varphi)\big\|_{L_2}^2=\biggl|\int_J(fg)\circ\varphi\biggl|=\\
\biggl|\int_{\varphi[J]}\big((fg)\circ\varphi\big)\circ\varphi^{-1}\cdot\big|\det D\varphi\big|\biggl|=
\biggl|\int_I(fg)\cdot\Big|\frac{b-a}{d-c}\Big|\biggl|=\\
\frac{b-a}{d-c}\cdot\biggl|\int_Ifg\biggl|\le\biggl|\int_Ifg\biggl|=\|f-g\|_{L_2}^2=\Big(d_{L_2}(f,g)\Big)^2
$$
for any $f,g\in C(I)$ so that we conclude that the application $\Phi$ above defined is an isometry and so it also continuous and thus if $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence on $C(I)$ converging to $f$ then the sequence $\big(\Phi(f_n)\big)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ on $J$ converges to $\Phi(f)$. However, what happens the inequality $(d-c)\le(b-a)$ does not holds? Anyway, this proves that if the inequality $(d-c)\le (b-a)$ holds then ther exist at least a homeomorphism from $ J$ to $I$ that carries the $L_2$ topology on $I$ to the $L_2$ topology on $J$.

So **first of all** I ask to know if the argumentations I gave about the uniform and pointwise convergence and the observations I did about the convergence on $P_0\cup N_0$ with respect the $L_2$ topology are correct and **then** I ask to clarify if the $L_2$ convergence on $I$ is equivalent to the $L_2$ convergence on $J$ through $\varphi$; moreover, I repeat I do not dislike to understand if the application $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism with respect the pointwise topology.

So could someone help me, please?

Comment: So $J$ is another non-degenerate closed interval in $\Bbb R$ and $I=[0,1]$ and you want $\Phi: C(I)\simeq C(J)$ in all topologies ? Do I understand correctly  ?

Comment: So I initially assumed that $I=[a,b]$ and $J=[c,d]$ was two generic intervals but effectively it seems that this is equivalent to say that $I=[0,1]$ and $J=[a,b]$ for any $a,b\in\Bbb R$, right?

Comment: Indeed if $C(I)\approx C\big([0,1]\big)$ through $\phi:I\rightarrow [0,1]$ and $C(J)\approx\big([0,1]\big)$ through $\varphi:J\rightarrow[0,1]$ then surely $C(I)\approx C(J)$ through $\phi^{-1}\circ\varphi$, right?

Comment: Yes fixing one interval to $[0,1]$ makes no difference. Being homeomorphic or isometric is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument for $\mathcal{T}_p$ can be simplified considerably; in that case $C([0,1])$ just has the subspace topology it inherits from $\Bbb R^I$ (or $\Bbb R^J$ resp.) in the product topology and it's quite clear that $\Phi: \Bbb R^I \to \Bbb R^J$ (which is a bijection when $\phi$ is) restricts to a bijection on $C(I)$ when $\phi$ is a homeomorphism of $I$: if $f \in C(I)$, we have $\Phi(f)=f \circ \phi \in C(J)$ as a composition of continuous functions and if $f \in C(J)$, it's clear too that $f'=f \circ \phi^{-1} \in C(I)$ and $\Phi(f')=f$ etc.

That $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism on the full products is clear by the universal property on products as $\pi^J_x \circ \Phi(f) = \pi^J_x \circ f \circ \phi = \pi^I_{\phi(x)}(f)$, for all $x \in J$ and $f \in \Bbb R^I$, so that $\pi^J_x \circ \Phi = \pi^I_{\phi(x)}$ is continuous for all projections etc. The same holds mutatis mutandis for $\Phi^{-1}(f)=f \circ \phi^{-1}$, which has the same form as $\Phi$. A map like $\Phi$ is often called the pull-back by $\phi$ and denoted $\phi_{\ast}$. So $(\phi_\ast)^{-1}=\phi^{-1}_\ast$ is what I was saying before, essentially.

So $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism between $C(I)$ and $C(J)$ in the pointwise topologies. You had quite similar considerations. But you don't have to consider any basic open sets: just know it's the product topology.

It's also quite clear that $\|\Phi(f)\|_\infty = \|f\|_\infty$ so that on the sup-norm topology we get a simple isometry and all is well.

I think too that standard integral facts tell us

**Edited:**
$\int_I f(x)dx = \alpha \int_J f(\phi(x)) dx$ for some $\alpha >0$ as we choose $\phi$ to be a suitable linear homeomorphism of intervals. So $\Phi$, or a scaled version of it, preserves $L^2$ inner products and so norm too etc. (adapted after comments discussion).

Comment: Okay, so essentially the application $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism with respect the pointwise topology because this topology is exactly the subspace topology induced by the product topology on $\Bbb R^I$, right?

Comment: Anyway unfortunately it seems to that generally $$∫_If(x)dx=∫_{\operatorname{int}I}f(x)\neq∫_{\operatorname{int}J}f(\phi(x))=∫_Jf(\phi (x))dx$$ because I know that the change of variable theorem says that if $\varphi:A\rightarrow B$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism of open set of $\Bbb R^n$ then the identity $$∫_A (f\circ\varphi)\big|\det(D\varphi)\big|=∫_Bf$$ holds for any continuous function $f$ defined on $B$. So in the integral on $J$ I do not see the term $\big|\det(D\varphi)\big|$: so perhaps there exist another version of the change of variable theorem or rather that I stated is incorrect?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro yeah you need a scaling factor in general. The $C^1$ requirement is too strong ( it’s for Riemann integrals IIRC) and you can choose $\phi$ to be linear and increasing and then you get a constant between the integrals and the norm. As long as it holds for one chosen $\phi$ it’s OK right?

Comment: Okay, so generally the $L_2$ topology on $C(I)$ is "equivalent" to the $L_2$ topology on $C(J)$ through $\phi$ provided that $\phi$ is a polynomial function of **unitary** degree and $I$ and $J$ has the **same** lenght, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro in those sets the $L^2$ topologies are homeomorphic ( linearly) by choosing a linear $\phi$. If the intervals have the same length they are even isometric otherwise “pseudo-isometric”.

Comment: Sorry I think to do not understand correctely: saying "in those sets..." you are referring to that intervals having the same length?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro no $C(I)$ and $C(J)$.

Comment: Okay. However, I do not see unfortunately how it can exist a linear map between two intervals: perhaps using the term linear you are referring to a map whose graph in $\Bbb R^2$ is a line, that is you are supposing that $\phi$ is properly the $\phi$ I defined at the end of the question? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro there is a linear homeomorphism of the form $\phi(x)=ax+b, a>0$ between only two bounded closed real intervals. It’s trivial to show. 2nd grade high school stuff.

Comment: Oh, yeah: I know this to the point that I put it in the question. The confusion I did was to think that $\phi$ is a linear application as application between vector spaces: indeed, it is necessary that $\phi(0)=0$ in order that a map between vector spaces can be linear, this is wrong?

Comment: Anyway I think I understood. So if $\phi$ is the map defined through the equation
$$
\phi(x):=\frac{b-a}{c-d}(x-c)+a
$$
for any $x\in\Bbb R$ then
$$
\Big(d_{L_2}\big(\Phi(f),\Phi(g)\big)\Big)^2=\Big(d_{L_2}(f\circ\varphi,g\circ\varphi)\Big)^2=\big\|(f\circ\varphi)-(g\circ\varphi)\big\|_{L_2}^2=\biggl|\int_J(fg)\circ\varphi\biggl|=\\
\biggl|\int_{\varphi[J]}\big((fg)\circ\varphi\big)\circ\varphi^{-1}\cdot\big|\det D\varphi\big|\biggl|=
\biggl|\int_I(fg)\cdot\Big|\frac{b-a}{d-c}\Big|\biggl|=
\frac{b-a}{d-c}\cdot\biggl|\int_Ifg\biggl|
$$

Comment: so that the map $\Phi'$ defined through the equation 
$$
\phi(f):=\sqrt{\frac{d-c}{b-a}}\Phi(f)
$$
for any $f\in C(I)$ is such that

Comment: $$
\Big(d_{L_2}\big(\Phi'(f),\Phi'(g)\big)\Big)^2=\Biggl(d_{L_2}\biggl(\sqrt{\frac{d-c}{b-a}}f\circ\varphi,\sqrt{\frac{d-c}{b-a}}g\circ\varphi\biggl)\Biggl)^2=\\\biggl\|\sqrt{\frac{d-c}{b-a}}(f\circ\varphi)-\sqrt{\frac{d-c}{b-a}}(g\circ\varphi)\biggl\|_{L_2}^2=
\frac{d-c}{b-a}\biggl|\int_J(fg)\circ\varphi\biggl|=\\
\frac{d-c}{b-a}\biggl|\int_{\varphi[J]}\big((fg)\circ\varphi\big)\circ\varphi^{-1}\cdot\big|\det D\varphi\big|\biggl|=\\
\frac{d-c}{b-a}\biggl|\int_I(fg)\cdot\Big|\frac{b-a}{d-c}\Big|\biggl|=
\biggl|\int_Ifg\biggl|=\big\|f-g\big\|_{L_2}^2=\Big(d_{L_2}(f,g)\Big)^2
$$

Comment: so that $\Phi'$ is an isometry between $C(I)$ and $C(J)$ and thus this are homeomorphic, right?

Comment: Yes, you could do that it seems; I call your last $\Phi'$ a pseudo-isometry. It's often enough to know it's a linear homeomorphism. There is a whole theory on what properties of $X$ and $Y$ have in common if you know that $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ are homeomorphic vs linearly homeomorphic in their pointwise topologies.  For the sup norm also is some literature and the $L_2$ topology isn't considered much (except as a Hilbert space on all Lebesgue square-integrable functions...) on $C(X)$, as it's incomplete.

Comment: Okay, very well: it is all clear now. Thanks very much for the assistance!!! See you soon... :)